# ActivityIndicator in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I am working on a project in which I have to navigate from one page (page1) to another (page2). As page2 is taking a long time to load so I was thinking to use `ActivityIndicator`, but it is not effective at all.

Please give me complete code to resolve my problem.

```
    Page(1)
    //code for tapping a label and to navigate to page2 
void onpage1tapped(Object sender,EventArgs args)
{  label1.Opacity=0.5;
   Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),()=>{label1.Opacity=1;return false;   })
   This.Navigate.PushAsync(new Page2());
} 

   Page(2)
 //constructor for page2
 public page2
 {   InitializeComponent();
      ActivityIndicator indicator=new ActivityIndicator{HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,Color=Color.Black,IsVisible=false};
      StackLayout stk=new StackLayout();
      stk.Children.Add(indicator);
    //Enabling activityindicator  
      indicator.IsRunning=true;
      indicator.IsVisible=true;

   //Below long time taking task
      Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        string resource = String.Format("ks.texts.BST.txt");
        //string resource = "advjava.texts.insertion.txt";
        using (Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                string line;
                while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
                {

                    Label l = new Label { Text = line, TextColor = Color.FromRgb(110, 139, 69), FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)) };
                    stk.Children.Add(l);

                }
            }
        }           

       //Disabling Activity indicator as the long task is complete
    indicator.IsVisible=false;
    indicator.IsRunning=false;
 }
```

Comment: I have already reffered following but not  helpful https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22309/how-to-show-a-loading-message-in-xamarin-forms-for-all-platforms

Comment: Please give me complete code for this problem instead of suggesting links because I have already watched all online help.

Comment: basically this is all about proper indication of page loading

Comment: Just show us your code? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a sample code, But it's logic is right and pretty good works for me. :)

```
        var indicator = new ActivityIndicator() {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };
        indicator.SetBinding(ActivityIndicator.IsVisibleProperty, "IsBusy", BindingMode.OneWay);
        indicator.SetBinding(ActivityIndicator.IsRunningProperty, "IsBusy", BindingMode.OneWay);

        var button = new Button() {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            Text = "BUTTON"
        };

        button.Clicked += (sender, e) => IsBusy = !IsBusy;

        var root = new StackLayout() {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = {
                button, 
                indicator
            }
        };

        Content = root;
```

You can refer this [Link](https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/32e1f5c1187d2a7e4835#file-app-cs-L44), which give a clear note on Github by **ChaseFlorell**.

Working Sample : [Github](https://github.com/teamtam/xamarin-forms-timesheet#xamarin-forms-timesheet)

Comment: no ,this will not work.It's not only about displaying an activity indicator but about displaying it to hide some heavy time consuming process. Please look at my code first.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs/). Have a look at it.. Hope it helps

[Here](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) is a documentation on how to implement Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs..
Hope it helps

Comment: sir,just look at my code and correct it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is with how your code is being read. It'll finish, then execute, but if you utilize the Task.Run, you'll be able to run on separate threads and keep that activity indicator up and running to show that your page is loading and your machine is busy.

```
void onpage1tapped(Object sender,EventArgs args) {  
    activityIndicator.IsVisible= true;
    Task.Run( () =>  {
        label1.Opacity=0.5;
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),()= {
            label1.Opacity=1;returnfalse;   
        })
        This.Navigate.PushAsync(new Page2());
    });
}
```