# busy loading in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have my page1.cs that loads 400 labels in a stacklayout which takes several seconds and am in need of a way to indicate that it is busy loading. I will most likely have other pages in my app that need the same ability.Please suggest a code for it keeping in mind I am a newbie.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActivityIndicator in Xamarin.Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903238/activityindicator-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ACR User Dialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/). This allows you to display a loading dialog from anywhere in the application. There are plenty of examples on the [GitHub](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) repository for it as well.  This blocks user input if you want, and has other types of dialogs as well, although I have only used the Loading Dialogs. The basic usage is just like this

```
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading...");
```

and

```
UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
```

If you want to do it for a task there is slightly different usage, but is provided in his samples. I currently am using this on Android and iOS and can assure you that they have a clean look.

Answer (score 0):

Forms has a built in [ActivityIndicator](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator/) you can use

Comment: I need code to use it .I have already tried ActivityIndicator....better you should look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903238/activityindicator-in-xamarin-forms